# How does mirror matter account for the faster than expected spin of gallaxies?

Tags: dark-matter, galaxies

To explain dark matter, some physicists have postulated the existence of [mirror matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_matter) as an alternative to [WIMPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_interacting_massive_particles), where mirror matter particles could interact with one another in the same way as visible particles, potentially forming mirror stars and galaxies (see [this article](http://www.technologyreview.com/view/418687/first-evidence-that-mirror-matter-may-fill-the-universe/) from the MIT Technology Review). I see how having a pair made up of a visible galaxy and a mirror galaxy in the same region of space might account for the missing mass, but how does it account for the stars on the outskirts of galaxies rotating faster than expected?

Comment: No idea what your question is about. Please expand and detail.

Comment: @RobJeffries Editted it, hopefully it makes sense now.

Comment: Not really, please provide references for, what on the face of it, seems decidedly "non mainstream".

Comment: To emphasize Rob's point, please point to peer reviewed work or recent preprints by reputable authors (with old preprints we're going ask why they haven't gotten published yet).

Comment: Are you talking about [mirror matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_matter), whose particles would theoretically interact with each other the same way visible particles do, so they could form mirror galaxies, planets etc.? [Here](http://www.technologyreview.com/view/418687/first-evidence-that-mirror-matter-may-fill-the-universe/) is a discussion from the MIT Technology Review of some physicists' claims that mirror matter could better explain the results of some dark matter detection experiments than the more common notion of weakly-interacting massive particles (WIMPs).

Comment: @Hypnosifl Ah Yes, that was it! I knew I wasn't dreaming